# Why is my HTTP get request giving me a 403 error?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I am trying to web scrape a site using a node.js server. I am using axios to make my http request. When I make the request I get a 403 error from the server.

Using Postman I can successfully make the request and return the HTML file. Why is Postman able get a 200 code and my request fails? What are some things I can try to successfully make the request?

//basic axios request Im using

```
axios.get(url)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: compare the request headers used by postman and axios, like accept or even user-agent

Answer (score 1):

Got exactly same situation: authorized only POST method working on postman, not working with axios.
Fixed it instead of calling `axios.post()`, calling:

```
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/post',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        },
        data: payload
      })
```

**For hint** : Refer this github [issue](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/2406)

Comment: This is only true if the backend doesn't expec auth to happen via ```GET```. It is possible to pass the headers via ```GET``` using axios.